# Retrieve encrypted JSON via PHP REST API

Tags: php, rest, encryption, php-curl

In localhost i'm trying to develope and test my REST API.
I have this code that send a JSON encrypted to the REST API

```
//The url i wish to send the POST request to
$url = "http://localhost/api/2.php";
$headers = array(
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Content-Type: application/json",
);

// Key
$encryption_key = "43274689933404c4bd47190b395f5e3a2c668fcca603c40ceb074c970047402d";
$iv = "274f5f54eff39aee1e4d2c614ccd99c9";
$method = "AES-256-CBC";

//The data to send via POST
$data = [
    'username'      => "RERERE",
    'password'      => "bbbb"
];

// Encrypted data
$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv));

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encrypted);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Now in 2.php file i can't retreive the content, i'm using something like this below but i got NULL

```
// Key
$encryption_key = "43274689933404c4bd47190b395f5e3a2c668fcca603c40ceb074c970047402d";
$iv = "274f5f54eff39aee1e4d2c614ccd99c9";
$method = "AES-256-CBC";

$json = file_get_contents('php://input',true);
$array = json_decode($json);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($array), $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

echo $decrypted;
```

Can someone help me to unsderstand what is wrong and if this is the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't see that you define your content as JSON anywhere, so trying to `json_decode` it makes no sense. Have you tried dumping the result of `file_get_contents('php://input',true)` to see what it really is?

Comment: Also _from the manual_ `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.` So just passing `$encrypted` wont help the situation either

Comment: Is this going to be an API that other people will be allowed to call? When you get it working??

Comment: Don't roll your own encryption. just se HTTPS.

Comment: @Quentin This must be and API that other people will be allowed to call.

Comment: @Ivan — Yes. Use HTTPS. Don't roll your own encryption.

Comment: @El_Vanja give dumping file_get_contents('php://input',true) give me string(0) ""

Comment: @ Quentin Hoe to use HTTPS?

Comment: Look at what is required to use this method !!!!!! If yo let me use this, you have to tell me the `Encryption_key` and the `iv`  In other words you have to give away the Crown Jewels. In short about as secure as an AshTray on a Motor Cycle

Comment: @Ivan — Depends on your webserver. Since you are using PHP the answer is probably "Pick a hosting plan with it turned on by default". More complex answers are available but would need to be tailored to exactly how you plan to host and deploy your code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the result in this way:

File who send the requests

```
//The url you wish to send the POST request to
$url = "http://localhost/api/2.php";

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);

$username = "aaaaaa";
$password = "bbbbbb";

// Key
$encryption_key = "43274689933404c4bd47190b395f5e3a2c668fcca603c40ceb074c970047402d";
$iv = "274f5f54eff39aee1e4d2c614ccd99c9";
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$usernameEncrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($username, $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv));
$passwordEncrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($password, $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv));

//The data to send via POST
$fields = [
    'username'       => $usernameEncrypted,
    'password'       => $passwordEncrypted
];
$fields = json_encode($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

And the file who receive the request and send the echo()

```
$encryption_key = "43274689933404c4bd47190b395f5e3a2c668fcca603c40ceb074c970047402d";
$iv = "274f5f54eff39aee1e4d2c614ccd99c9";
$method = "AES-256-CBC";

$datiInArray = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

$usernameCrypted = $datiInArray["username"];
$passwordCrypted = $datiInArray["password"];

$username = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($usernameCrypted), $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
$password = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($passwordCrypted), $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

// Here echo the result
echo $username."<br>".$password;
```